# Working with GIT on two remote repositories

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket

We're giving development services for a company and they are also getting service from another company and they don't want them to be aware of us.

They're using a git repository which I've full access (but I must avoid writing anything to it) and also we've another repository for our own developments.

I would like to update our master branch with their code once a week and meanwhile I want to continue pushing our developments to another branch. And after a while when other companies development has finished, I'm planning to merge our developments to our master branch for preparing a release.

Also keeping other company's development history would be great!

I'm using SourceTree as GIT interface, any instructions with it also would be great!

What kind of flow should I follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to merge from the other company’s branch to your master branch, this is an **unrelated-histories merge**. But SourceTree is not support merge for --allow-unrelated-histories, so you’d better to use `git command line`. Below is git command for your reference:

```
git clone <URL for your own repo>
git remote add otherrepo <URL for the other company’s repo>
git pull otherrepo                                      #pull otherrepo to your local repo
git merge otherrepo/master --allow-unrelated-histories  #merge otherrepo’s master branch to your local master branch
```

After the other company’s repo is updated, you need to use `git pull otherreop` and `git merge otherrepo/master --allow-unrelated-histories` again.

After all the things finished, you can use `git checkout master` and `git merge develop` to merge develop branch to master branch.

Answer (score 0):

Your local repo can point to more than one remote repo.
The object which points to a remote repo is called a "remote".
Typically the remote repo you cloned from will be named origin in your local repo.
You can create a remote with a different name (e.g. customer-origin).
You can then clone from customer-origin, create a local branch to work on, and push that branch to your company's repo (probably called origin).
Then, when you want to update from the customer, switch back to the branch you cloned from them, and pull from the remote called customer-origin.
Then you can merge that to your development branch.
In sourcetree I have read that settings->add is where a new remote is added, but I am not an expert in using source tree.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can add the other company rep as a new remote

```
git remote add companyName https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

---

For the weekly updates:

1. git pull companyName master
2. In SourceThree you can put a tag here to control the updates :)
3. git push origin master

If this is the only way to change the master, it would not make any conflicts. I imagine the hotfix will occur in the *companyName master*.

---

Release Merge:

Just merge it normally, using: `git merge dev` and resolve the conflicts.

---

hope it helps

EDIT:

ps: You can also use 'git flow' in the development and Release... it will prevent some problems xD